# how do I perform tasks before loading a webview url in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

so I can't seem to figure out a way to perform some tasks before loading a url in ios webview.
Like in android we can use shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, String url) {
   ///sometask
}
```

but I can't find a function that does something like this in ios.
Say a user clicked on a href tag inside the webview that takes it to different page, how do I know what link that tag takes the user to? before changing the page.

Basically I want to check what url the webpage is about to load and perform extra steps according to that url.

Comment: Check `WKNavigationDelegate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use WKNavigationDelegate**

set navigationDelegate in viewDidLoad

**self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self**

Observe URL in below navigationDelegate Method.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let urlString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString{
                  
                  print(urlString)
             }
         }

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Comment: Why us `DispatchQueue.main.async`? And you should always call `decisionHandler`, no?

Comment: No, It depends upon use of url, I have used it for to performing UI related operation thats why I added. You can ignore if you don't want to use.

Comment: @Larme I forgot to add decisionHandler(.allow).

Comment: thanks! works like a charm and does exactly what I wanted :)